# How to Create Function in Code First?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Is it possible to use `Code First` to create a database function in sql server?

Like

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnIsPaid] ...
```

---

Here is how I have worked it out based on ChrFin's suggestion. I marked it as the answer. But let me keep a more detailed record here.

In the `Package Manager Console,`Add-Migration AddFnIsPaid`.

This will create a `DbMigration` class prefixed with timestamp.

In this migration class, I have a create script and drop script for `Up()` and `Down()` method:

```
public partial class AddFnIsPaid : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        Sql(_createFunctionScript);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        Sql(DropFunctionScript);
    }


    #region SQL Scripts
    private readonly string _createFunctionScript = string.Concat(
            "CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnIsPaid] ",
            "(",
            ...
            ") ",
            "RETURNS bit ",
            "AS ",
            "BEGIN ",
            ...
            "END"
            );

    private const string DropFunctionScript = "DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[fnIsPaid]";  
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "use Code First to *create* a database function"?  You can't emit a function to the database from your C# code, no.  But you can create one yourself and map the code to use it.

Comment: My! Are we sometimes too eager to downvote a valid question? llya certainly points me to a good direction. Any comments would be helpful to bring me out of dark. I really appreciate.

Comment: @Blaise is there any essential reason why you took the sql statement into a script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can only tell it to map CRUD actions to stored procedures (EF 6+) with e.g.:

```
modelBuilder
   .Entity<Post>()
   .MapToStoredProcedures();
```

But you can execute custom SQL in your migration:

```
public override void Up()
{
    Sql("CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnIsPaid] ...");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. My understanding: 1) add the `MapToStoredProcedures()` to my fluentAPI. 2) `Add-Migration` to generate the scaffolding migration code. 3) add the sql script manually in that migration code. 4) run an `Update-Database`. Am I correct?

Comment: Ooops. `MapToStoredProcedures()` generated `_Insert`, `_Update` and `_Delete`, which I do not need. So what is your purpose of `MapToStoredProcedures()`, ChrFin?

Comment: `MapToStoredProcedures() generated _Insert, _Update and _Delete` => thats exactly what its for. If you do not need that don't add it and add an empty migration via `Add-Migration` and add your SQL script, but you already figured that out ;-)...

Answer (score 5):

I know old question but in case anyone in need. if you prefer a more simple flexible way. create a method in the Configuration.cs file. Then put your sql script in \App_Data directory that way you can put any SQL script you like in the .SQL file. Works fine in MVC 5.0, EF6.0

```
    private void CreateProcedure(MvcAppDb context)
    {  
        string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString() + @"/Procedures.sql";
        Console.WriteLine(path);
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
        string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(script);  
    }
```

Then add a call to the Configuration.cs and you all set.

```
 protected override void Seed(MvcAppDb context)
    {

        CreateProcedure(context);
```